# Install oracle on an AIX VM virtualizing with QEMU

Tags: qemu, aix, oracle

I installed a Linux VM in the virtual box, and inside it I installed the QEMU package and virtualized an AIX 7.2 image. The entire installation went correctly.

But when I try to install an Oracle inside the AIX VM that is virtualized by QEMU, I get a Segmentation fault message.

Start VM Qemu:

```
ppc64-softmmu/qemu-system-ppc64 -cpu POWER8 \
-machine pseries -m 8192 \
-drive file=hdisk0.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0 \
-device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi \
-device scsi-hd,drive=drive-virtio-disk0 \
-cdrom AIX72.iso \
-net nic -net tap,script=no,ifname=tap0 \
-prom-env "boot-command=boot disk:" \
-prom-env "input-device=/vdevice/vty@71000000" \
-prom-env "output-device=/vdevice/vty@71000000" \
--daemonize
```

Command:

```
$ ./runInstaller
./runInstaller[238]: 6095358 Segmentation fault
```

Details:

```
$ ulimit -a
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         2097151
data(kbytes)         131072
stack(kbytes)        32768
memory(kbytes)       32768
coredump(blocks)     2097151
nofiles(descriptors) 2000
threads(per process) unlimited
processes(per user)  unlimited

$ /usr/sbin/lsattr -E -l sys0 -a realmem
realmem 8388608 Amount of usable physical memory in Kbytes False
```

Links:

[Guide QEMU](https://kwakousys.wordpress.com/2020/09/06/run-aix-7-2-on-x86-with-qemu/)

[Guide Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e48740/inst_task.htm#AXDBI1242)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129740/discussion-between-luis-henrique-and-gerard-h-pille).

Answer (score 0):

You should use qemu-6.1 ,this can install oracle and start it normally.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _why_ you think using that specific version will solve the OPs problem.